# Is there a way to make the toaster notification in windows 10 pop-up when you convert the python file to an executable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a code such that it prompts a popup window and when you click the only button of the window a toaster notification would appear. However, if I convert the code from python to executable, only the popup window would appear. How can I fix this problem such that both the popup window and toaster notification would appear when I run the executable?

Here is the code that I converted to executable:

```py
import mpmath as mp
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from mpmath import *
import tkinter as tk

# Pop-up Window #
LARGE_FONT = ("Arial", 12)
NORM_FONT = ("Arial", 10)
SMALL_FONT = ("Arial", 8)


def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Notification")
    label = tk.Label(popup, text=msg)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=50, padx=50)
    B1 = tk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command=popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()

def windowspopup():
    toast = ToastNotifier()
    toast.show_toast('Message A', 'Message B')

# Calculatory Algorithm and output / Execution Time Delayer #
mp.dps = 100

sum = mpf(0)
for i in range(1, 99):
    f = mpf(1) / mpf(mpf(i) ** mpf(2))
    sum = mpf(sum) + mpf(f)
    if i == 98:
        f1 = len(str(sum))
        f2 = mpf((mpf(6) * mpf(sum)) ** mpf(0.5))
        # print(f1)
        # print(f2)
        popupmsg('Hello, click my ok button and an important message would appear ')
        windowspopup()
```

Thank you in advance!